# Creating unit tests for assuring immutability

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, immutability

I have designed an [immutable class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), because I want to have value-semantics for it. I wrote a hint into the commentary section of the class

`// "This class is immutable, don't change this when adding new features to it."`

But I know, sometimes those commentaries are overlooked by other team members, so I would like to create a unit test as an additional safeguard. Any idea how to accomplish this? Can one inspect a class via reflection to make sure only the constructors change it's inner state?

(Using C# 2.0 and NUnit, if that's important for anyone).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An example to back up my comment on how you can use `FieldInfo.IsInitOnly` recursively to test for immutability.

There may be more special cases to consider like how I have handled `string`, but it will only give false negatives I believe, i.e. will tell you something is mutable that is not, not the other way around.

The logic is, every field must be `readonly` and be an immutable type itself. Note that it will not cope with self referential types or circular references.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ImmutableTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class AssertImmutableTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Is_int_immutable()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(Immutable<int>());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Is_string_immutable()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(Immutable<string>());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Is_custom_immutable()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(Immutable<MyImmutableClass>());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Is_custom_mutable()
        {
            Assert.IsFalse(Immutable<MyMutableClass>());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Is_custom_deep_mutable()
        {
            Assert.IsFalse(Immutable<MyDeepMutableClass>());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Is_custom_deep_immutable()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(Immutable<MyDeepImmutableClass>());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Is_propertied_class_mutable()
        {
            Assert.IsFalse(Immutable<MyMutableClassWithProperty>());
        }

        private static bool Immutable<T>()
        {
            return Immutable(typeof(T));
        }

        private static bool Immutable(Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsPrimitive) return true;
            if (type == typeof(string)) return true;
            var fieldInfos = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var isShallowImmutable = fieldInfos.All(f => f.IsInitOnly);
            if (!isShallowImmutable) return false;
            var isDeepImmutable = fieldInfos.All(f => Immutable(f.FieldType));
            return isDeepImmutable;
        }
    }

    public class MyMutableClass
    {
        private string _field;
    }

    public class MyImmutableClass
    {
        private readonly string _field;
    }

    public class MyDeepMutableClass
    {
        private readonly MyMutableClass _field;
    }

    public class MyDeepImmutableClass
    {
        private readonly MyImmutableClass _field;
    }

    public class MyMutableClassWithProperty
    {
        public string Prop { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm seeing something wrongly, but a class containing a public int, would be considered immutable given this example, right? While it is in fact mutable.

Comment: @TonniTielens Depends on what you mean, `public int A {get; private set;}` mutable, `public int A {get;}` not mutable. `public int A;` mutable.

Comment: This is missing a check for enums, which are similar to primitive types            type.GetTypeInfo().IsEnum

Comment: Thanks, feel free to add a test and fix it up.

Answer (score 8):

You could check that the class is sealed, and using reflection check that each field is read-only (using [`FieldInfo.IsInitOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.isinitonly.aspx)).

Of course, that only ensures *shallow* immutability - it wouldn't stop someone from putting a `List<int>` field in there, and then changing the contents of the list.

Comment: Good idea this, I have used this to create a `AssertImmutable<T>()` method which you can call recusively on the field types to assert deep immutability.

Comment: @weston Have you shared this?

Comment: @denver I have now, it's recreated from memory and you may find some more edge cases like `string` http://stackoverflow.com/a/22251440/360211

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've heard of [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/), but this tool allows you to "introspect" over your source code and compiled assemblies and do all sorts of magic including dependency checking and much more.

One such check is a check for immutability. For instance, I have an `IImmutable` marker interface, and NDepend fails my build if any types have this interface but are mutable, using the following query:

```
WARN IF Count > 0 IN SELECT TYPES WHERE 
  Implement "MyCompany.MyAssemblies.Dto.IImmutable" AND
  !IsImmutable
```

You can also configure it to generate violation reports, as well as failing builds.

Obviously this isn't actually a unit test. However, it can be integrated as part of your build, and fail your build just as a unit test would, so I thought I'd mention it!

See [here](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#Immutable) for more info on what it actually does and how.

Comment: +1, this answer is useful, too, but I can only accept one. Perhaps I will try NDepend to see if is worth the price four our projects.